# Nginx Configuration with URI on Domain

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx

I need your help with regards to my nginx configuration file. I need to install my site with a /jp uri on it domain for the homepage. I already tried using a simple domain and the site works, so I know that the problem is not on my laravel configuration. The site is loading but it's showing no errors and no content at all. Will you please help me figure out what's wrong with this configuration?

Website Link: https://booking.bgbridalgallery.com/jp/

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/booking.bgbridalgallery.com/before/*;

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
# include upstreams/bgbridalgallery.com;

map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}


server {
    server_name www.booking.bgbridalgallery.com;
    return 301 https://booking.bgbridalgallery.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    # listen [::]:80;
    server_name .booking.bgbridalgallery.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/bgbridalgallery.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/booking.bgbridalgallery.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/booking.bgbridalgallery.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!3DES';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

#   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    expires $expires;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/bgbridalgallery.com/server/*;

    location / {
        return 301 https://booking.bgbridalgallery.com/jp;
    }    

    location /jp {
        alias /home/forge/bgbridalgallery.com/public/jp/current/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @jp;

    if ($request_uri ~* ".(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|png)$") {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            break;
        }  

        location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @jp {
        rewrite /jp/(.*)$ /jp/index.php?/ last;
    }

    location /jp/booking {
        alias /home/forge/booking/jp/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @jpbooking;

        if ($request_uri ~* ".(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|png)$") {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            break;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @jpbooking {
        rewrite /jp/booking/(.*)$ /jp/booking/index.php?/ last;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/booking.bgbridalgallery.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/booking.bgbridalgallery.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/booking.bgbridalgallery.com/after/*;
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificate appears to be set to weddingvideo.jp, It seems this configuration is not applied, I do suggest you update certificates. You can run a test with on the desired server name with

> sudo certbot --nginx --dry-run

If it succede, you can then re-install or re-deploy them with similar command, but it allows you to reinstall or get a new certificate

> sudo certbot --nginx

If this works I'd check anyway Nginx configuration with

> sudo nginx -t

then apply it with command

> sudo service nginx reload